# Add some logic to login process with Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

i'm in the process of migrating a project to backpack. I'm using ad authentication, which i was able integrate with backpack. In the current project I have some logic in order to assign roles based on AD groups belonging, now I have this process implemented in the login function inside the login controller. How can I implement this process in backpack? I don't have access to the auth controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I created a Listener for the Login event and added there all the role assign logic.

Answer (score 1):

the docs have an example for Register, but the idea is the same for login, have a look at: https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/5.x/base-how-to#add-one-or-more-fields-to-the-register-form-1

Cheers